# Accessing metadata from HKSampleQuery(Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-watch, healthkit

So I am following the apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksamplequery)

What I am trying to do is access the HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext key on our HKSampleQuery. I need to do something if HrContext = 1 and hr is above a certain number.

Here is the code:

```
  func sampleQ() -> HKQuery{
      let pre = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date().lastweek, end: nil)

      let que = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heartRateType, predicate: pre, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: nil) {
         query, results, error in

         guard let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
            fatalError("An error occured fetching the user's tracked food. In your app, try to handle this error gracefully. The error was: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
         }
         print (samples)



         for sample in samples {
            print (sample)

            guard let hrContext =
               sample.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext] as? String else {

                  break
            }

            print(hrContext)

            print (hrContext+"i am the context")
         }




      }

      return que
   }
```

the code is then being executed here:

```
func startToMeasure() {
        self.healthStore.execute(self.createStreamingQuery())
      self.healthStore.execute(self.sampleQ())
    }
```

For some reason, all I get in the log is the normal streaming heartrate as well as the printed metadata(although I can't access it, and it isn't printing any of my hrContext statements)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The value of the heart rate-motion context itself is an `NSInteger` and therefore cannot be cast to a `String` - this integer can be mapped to an enum case of [`HKHeartRateMotionContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkheartratemotioncontext).

```
let context = sample.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext] as? NSNumber
```